# Using purr to iterate over list of file directories to read max subfolder where file exists

Tags: r, purrr

The code referenced below seeks to find the most recent year within `workbook_dir`, then the most recent month to then read the excel file within the `readxl` command below.  The issue I'm having is when the file doesn't exist, but the subfolder is already created.  How would I change below in order to find the most recent file path where the referenced file actually exists?  I would imaging some form of `purrr`?  So in this case, if the file doesn't exist in `9`, then iterate to check whether it exists in `8`.  If it doesn't exist in the subfolder `1` within `2021`, then check `12` within `2020`.  Code that gets me most of the way there is below.

```
# path for workbook log files
workbook_dir <- "Z:/Ac/Iron/STAR"

# list files in directory
year_dirs = fs::dir_ls(workbook_dir)

# Find the latest year and get that directory
years = str_extract(year_dirs, '\\d{4}/?$') %>% parse_number()
latest_year_dir = year_dirs[which.max(years)]

# Repeat for month
month_dirs = fs::dir_ls(latest_year_dir)
months = str_extract(month_dirs, '\\d{2}/?$') %>% parse_number()
latest_month_dir = month_dirs[which.max(months)]
# read excel file
file <- readxl::read_excel(file.path(latest_month_dir, "Working", "Group Workbook Log.xlsx"))
```

Comment: Did you meant the `years_dirs` or the `month_dirs` is returning length 0?

Comment: How about just creating a data frame of all paths using `list.files(recursive = TRUE)` then filtering to valid `.xlsx` files. Then create a date column from the year/month values in the paths, and filter to `max(Date)` to get your path? That way it's all vectorized, no recursive looping required.

Comment: Doing that would immediately eliminate empty subdirectories so you don't have to iterate backwards.

Comment: The month directory for 9 within 2021 is returning the file doesn’t exist, but the file exists in 8 within 2021.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer with a little pseudo code here. I'm going to assume your directories are in the format /year/month/file (e.g. `./2020/01/File.xlsx`)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# get a list of all files in all subdirectories - working directory 
# should be the parent folder of the folder(s) containing years
# or give that path directly to list.files()

df <- list.files(recursive = TRUE) %>% data.frame(paths = .)

# filter to .xlsx files
most_recent_file <- df %>% filter(grepl("\\.xlsx$", paths)) %>%
    # extract Year/Month then create a Date column
    mutate(
      Year = str_extract(paths,"(?<=\\/)\\d{4}(?=\\/)"),
      Month = str_extract(paths,"(?<=\\/)\\d{2}(?=\\/)"),
      Date = as.Date(paste(Year, Month, "01", sep = "-"))
    ) %>%
    # filter to most recent date
    filter(Date == max(Date)) %>%
    # extract the relevant path as a string
    pull(paths)
```

At which point we will have filtered `df` to (assuming there's only one file per month) a single file path which can then be read into R.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately I am getting NA  in the year column.  File path is something like: Z:/Ac/Iron/STAR/2021/09/Working/abc.xlsx

Comment: But month is working correctly? If I run `str_extract("Z:/Ac/Iron/STAR/2021/09/Working/abc.xlsx", "(?<=\\/)\\d{4}(?=\\/)")` I get "2021" returning correctly. Is that the case for you as well?

Comment: The pattern that regex statement is looking for is specifically 4 digits preceded and followed by forward slashes `/2021/`. I believe `list.files` uses forward slashes, but you can also express a path with double back slashes \\2021\\ and that wouldn't match